# Name Error in Django - Nested Function in Views Function - Saving to Database

Tags: python, django, function, nested, nested-function

Using Django, While trying to save the answers from the User to the Database, it is showing me a Name Error. I have nested a function inside a views function, it works correctly when i do not attempt to save the data to the database. But once i try to put in code inside the views function to save the data, it produces this name error.  Below are the files with the code,

**models.py file**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class ansquestions(models.Model):
    m_invested = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    p_return = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    years = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inflation_yes_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    r_output = models.TextField(default=True)
    date_answered = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py file**

```
from django import forms
from .models import ansquestions

class ansquestionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ansquestions
        fields = ['m_invested', 'p_return', 'years', 'inflation_yes_no', 'r_output', 'date_answered', 'author'

]
```

**views.py file** ***(Note : the fvinvestment function is nested under investmentfvcalc function. when pasting in here, its not showing as indented under the investmentfvcalc, but in my real code the fvinvestment function is indented and nested under the investmetncalc function. )***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
#from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import ansquestions
from .forms import ansquestionsForm


def investmentfv(request):
    idata = { 'tmi':tmi, 'pry':pry, 'ys':ys, 'qinf':qinf }
    return render(request, 'fvalueapp/investmentfv.html', idata)




 def investmentfvcalc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ansquestionsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            total_i = request.POST.get["m_invested", '']
            perc_r = request.POST.get["p_return", '']
            years_i = request.POST.get["years", '']
            makeup_infl = request.POST.get["inflation_yes_no", '']
            ansquestions_obj = ansquestions(m_invested=total_i, p_return=perc_r, years=years_i, inflation_yes_no=makeup_infl)
            ansquestions_obj.save() 

            

def fvinvestment():
        global fv_i_value
        global r_output
        #global makeup_infl ( global variable might be needed for technique for above. as error says makeup_inf is not defined ) 
        if makeup_infl=='no':
            i_return = (float(perc_r))
        elif makeup_infl=='yes' and int(years_i)<=5:
            i_return = (2+float(perc_r))
        elif makeup_infl=='yes' and int(years_i)>5 and int(years_i)<=9.99 :
            i_return = (4 + float(perc_r))
        elif makeup_infl=='yes' and int(years_i)>= 10 :    
            i_return = ( 6 + float(perc_r))
                
        
        fv_i_value = int(total_i) * (1 + (i_return)*.01) ** int(years_i)

        r_output = 'Your money would grow to the total of ' + str(fv_i_value) +' dollars at the end of this timeframe.'                     
        
    
    fvinvestment()   


  

  

    
idata = { 'tmi':tmi, 'pry':pry, 'ys':ys, 'qinf':qinf, 'r_output': r_output }
return render (request, 'fvalueapp/fvinvestmentcalcresults.html', idata)
```

**Errors :**

**Running the above code it gives me the error "NameError at investmentfv/Investementfvcalc" "free variable 'makeup_infl' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope " i than later would put the variable "makeup_infl" as a Global variable in the fvinvestment function, it than would produce error "NameError - name 'makeup_infl' is not define**

Comment: You should not call a function like this in views.py and expect it to work. Django routes web requests to one view function. If you want to get more detail about the error you should also copy the complete traceback of the NameError in question.

Comment: Update : i forgot to add the code for the saving of the data which is producing the error, its up there now.

Comment: @edgars Also running the above code it gives me the error "NameError at investmentfv/Investementfvcalc" "free variable 'makeup_infl' referenced  before assignment in enclosing scope "   i than later would put the variable "makeup_infl" as a Global variable in the fvinvestment function, it than would produce error "NameError - name 'makeup_infl' is not defined

Comment: Important : the fvinvestment function is nested under investmentfvcalc function. when pasting in here, its not showing as indeneted under the investmentfvcalc, but in my real code the fvinvestment function is indented and nested under the investmetncalc function.

Comment: Nesting a view function inside another view function goes against django best practices, and frankly it's not surprising in the least that it's resulting in scope errors.  Instead, separate your views entirely, or perhaps write a Class Based View and put the logic from your nested view into its methods.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Here i nested a regular function under a views function. I did not nest a views function underneath another views function. I have edited the title of the post to make that a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Change fvinvestment to global scope, pass in these variables: years_i and makeup_infl

```
def fvinvestment(years_i, makeup_infl):
    ....
```

This will also solve your makeup_infl not defined error

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. When you say make the fvinvestment to global scope, do you mean by not using this as a nested function, and to un-indent the fvinvestement function, so it would be a separate function in itself ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Nesting view functions isn't good practice in Django views